# RAM meanings when renting a dedicated server

Tags: memory, dedicated-server

8 GB DDR3 RAM
v.s.
4 x 2048 MB DDRII PC667 RAM

What is the main difference between 8 and "4 x 2048"

They both equal the same amount of RAM right?

And what is DDR3 and DDRII?

Comment: How is this off topic?  That is ridiculus

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things:

- First, the two options you list have different performing RAM (DDR3 vs. DDR2).
- Second, some architectures (e.g. NUMA) perform differently (better or worse depending on the workload) with memory that is separated into multiple buses over memory that is accessed over the same bus.
- Finally, there could be other differences between the RAM.  Note that the DDR2 RAM is listed as being PC667, but there is no measurement listed for the DDR3 option.

Answer (score 0):

They're each 8GB of memory -- one is of DDR3 and one is of DDRII.

DDR3 is generally preferred over DDRII. [This page](http://www.build-gaming-computer-guide.com/ddr3-vs-ddr2.html) talks about the difference between the two.